# PDFBOX issue - How to import PDFBOX in androi studio?

Tags: android, pdfbox

i'm new in android platform. I've got an [github](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) project**(PDF-BOX)**. In where, the pdfbox lib is already imported. But i would like to know the process how to import **PDF-BOX Library** in a project step by step. :).

Comment: instead of asking for a step by step solution why don't you look at the sample code they have provided in the same repository? https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/tom_roush/pdfbox/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: thnx vai. Uporwala apko vala rakhe...:)

Comment: hope you got it :p